# find maximum value recursively with a List

Tags: java, list, recursion

This method I'm trying to write finds the maximum value of integers in a list, and for the assignment I have to use recursion. I think I understand the concept of recursion, but doing it with Lists or arrays is something I don't understand. Does it always require splitting the List or array in half? Anyways, this code will compile, but I'm getting an IndexOutOfBounds error in a line I've commented below. Does it look remotely close to what I should be doing?

```
public static final int findMaxRecursively(List<Integer> numbers) {
int max = 0;

     if(numbers.size() == 1)
       return numbers.size();

     List<Integer> bottomHalf = new ArrayList<Integer>(numbers.size()/2);
     for (int i= 0; i<numbers.size()/2;i++){
         if (bottomHalf.get(i) > max) // here's where the IndexOutOfBounds error occurs
          max = bottomHalf.get(i);
          }
          findMaxRecursively(bottomHalf);

     List<Integer> topHalf = new ArrayList<Integer>(numbers.size()/2);
     for(int i = numbers.size()/2; i< numbers.size(); i++){
         if (topHalf.get(i) > max)   
         max = topHalf.get(i);
    }
         findMaxRecursively(topHalf);

         return max;
}
```

Comment: From the docs, `E get(int index) Throws:
    IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the index is out of range (index < 0 || index >= size())` Even if you do `List<Integer myArray = new ArrayList<>(4);`, you will still get `myArray.size() == 0` to be true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your recursive calls make no sense, since you are passing to them empty lists, and even if they returned the correct value, you are not doing anything with the returned value.

In order to find the max element recursively you should split the list. The most efficient split is to two equal parts.

Creating a List by `new ArrayList<Integer>(numbers.size()/2)` doesn't copy to this list half the elements of the original list. It just creates an empty list whose initial capacity is half the size of the original list.
You can use `List<E> subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex);` to get a view of a portion of the list.

And when `numbers.size() == 1`, you should return `numbers.get(0)` not `numbers.size()`.

Finally, having the for loops defeats the purpose of a recursive solution. In a recursive solution you just make 2 recursive calls to get the max value of the bottom half and the top half, and then you compare the two returned values and return the larger one.

```
public static final int findMaxRecursively(List<Integer> numbers) 
{
     if(numbers.size() == 1)
         return numbers.get(0);

     List<Integer> bottomHalf = numbers.subList(0,numbers.size()/2);
     int bottom = findMaxRecursively(bottomHalf);

     List<Integer> topHalf = numbers.subList(numbers.size()/2,numbers.size());
     int top = findMaxRecursively(topHalf);

     return top>bottom?top:bottom;
}
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you! I didn't know about the subList method, but this makes a lot of sense.